# plotting multiple histograms in grid

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I am running following code to draw histograms in 3 by 3 grid for 9 varaibles.However, it plots only one variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_histograms(df, variables, n_rows, n_cols):
    fig=plt.figure()
    for i, var_name in enumerate(variables):
        ax=fig.add_subplot(n_rows,n_cols,i+1)
        df[var_name].hist(bins=10,ax=ax)
        plt.title(var_name+"Distribution")
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're adding subplots correctly but you call `plt.show` for each added subplot which causes what has been drawn so far to be shown, i.e. one plot. If you're for instance plotting inline in IPython you will only see the last plot drawn.

Matplotlib provides some nice [examples](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) of how to use subplots.

Your problem is fixed like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_histograms(df, variables, n_rows, n_cols):
    fig=plt.figure()
    for i, var_name in enumerate(variables):
        ax=fig.add_subplot(n_rows,n_cols,i+1)
        df[var_name].hist(bins=10,ax=ax)
        ax.set_title(var_name+" Distribution")
    fig.tight_layout()  # Improves appearance a bit.
    plt.show()

test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30, 9), columns=map(str, range(9)))
draw_histograms(test, test.columns, 3, 3)
```

Which gives a plot like:

[image: subplot histograms]

Answer (score 14):

In case you don't really worry about titles, here's a one-liner

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 9)))
df.hist(color='k', alpha=0.5, bins=10)
```

[image]